# Solutions to differential equation when two particular solutions are known

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this relatively standard problem, but I don't know the method of solving it. 
Here it is:

[image]

"Determine the value for the constant $a$.

Determine an expression for $q(t)$.

Is there some symmetry that I'm supposed to use to solve this, or is there a formula or sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this : 
$$x'_1+ax_1=x'_2+ax_2 \implies a = ?$$
Then you can deduce $q(t)=x'_1+ax_1$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to do with that? I don't know what $x_1'+ax_1$ is, nor do I know what the other term is. I can't really see why $a=5$.

Comment: @Carl you have been given $x_1$ and also $x_2$ the unknown is simply a.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I know a particular procedure, but by observing the two solutions given, the $3e^{2t}$ does not vary between both of them, so we can assume it is the non-homogeneous term. We can then solve $x'(t) + a \cdot x(t) = 0$, where $\{x_{1}, x_{2}\} - 3e^{2t}$ are solutions to the homogeneous equations. This gives that $a = -5$ for the solutions to agree. Substituting $x_{1}(t)$ and $x_{2}(t)$ into the equation, we get that $x_{1}' - 5x_{1} = 5e^{5t} +6e^{2t} - 5(e^{5t} + 3e^{2t}) = -9e^{2t} \implies q(t) = -9e^{2t}$. Similarly, $x_{2}' - 5x_{2} = -5e^{5t} +6e^{2t} - 5(-e^{5t}+3e^{2t}) = -9e^{2t}$. Hence, $x_{1}(t)$ and $x_{2}(t)$ are solutions to the equation, 
$$
x'(t) - 5 \cdot x(t) = -9e^{2t}
$$
So $a = -5$ and $q(t) = -9e^{2t}$. I understand this was a by-inspection sort of solution so feel free to ask questions.